# Using git svn clone

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

In One of the Project I am working, I have been tasked to **migrate SVN repository to Git**.

I have seen some Answers how to do it, I was trying to use **git svn clone to clone svn repository to git**. As Users are frequently using SVN repository I wanted to know using git svn clone will not hamper anything in the SVN repository and users will be able to use it while git svn clone is running. Also it will not break anything in the SVN and does it only clones the repository in git.
I know it might be a stupid question but I was bit apprehensive to using it.

Thanks in advance for any answers to this.

Comment: `git svn clone` doesn't change anything in the svn repository, it just connects the same as `svn checkout` and converts stuff to git format on your computer. When you do `git svn dcommit` it converts it back to svn format before it sends it to the server

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helps. I will try git svn clone to clone a repository from svn to git.